# Create SOAP Request and Display Response

Tags: php, xml, soap

How do you send SOAP data and then display the response you get via PHP? I do have the WSDL file. I just want to learn how to send and show the response.

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ser="http://service.application.example.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
 <ser:addPlace>
<arg0>
<addDate>2015-02-04</addDate>
<ClientID>98745</ClientID>
</arg0>
 </ser:addPlace>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: If you search online for "php soap", you will find plenty of information. Is there a particular problem you're having with the examples you can find?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoapClient in php (http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

```
<?php
$client = new \SoapClient("http://urlToWsdl/soap.wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
$params = array('arg0' => array('addDate' => '2015-02-04', 'ClientID' => 98745));
$result =   $client->__soapCall('addPlace', $params);
var_dump($result);
```